# convert logback.xml to log4j.properties

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, logback

How can I convert this logback.xml to an equivalent log4j.properties?

```
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logging-${byDay}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I am changing my logging system from logback to log4j. I already have this logback.xml file for logback. So need an equivalent log4j.properties file for log4j.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend read official docs. But in your case:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/logs/logging-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! Will vote up once I get required reputation.

Answer (score 0):

how would I convert?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>return message.contains("LLDC");    </expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/etc/ccp/lldc/applogs/lldc.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>lldc-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>400MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator> <!-- Default is ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
                <expression>return message.contains("LLDC");    </expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="lldc" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```